# aspnetboilerplate internal 500 error on recursive entity lookup

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, recursion, aspnetboilerplate

I am getting the following error when query a recursive entity lookup.

**Error**:

> *{"message":"An error has occurred.","exceptionMessage":"There is an action GetCategories defined for api controller app/category but with a different HTTP Verb. Request verb is GET. It should be Post","exceptionType":"System.Web.HttpException","stackTrace":"   at Abp.WebApi.Controllers.Dynamic.Selectors.AbpApiControllerActionSelector.GetActionDescriptorByActionName(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, DynamicApiControllerInfo controllerInfo, String actionName)\r\n   at Abp.WebApi.Controllers.Dynamic.Selectors.AbpApiControllerActionSelector.SelectAction(HttpControllerContext controllerContext)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.ApiController.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at Castle.Proxies.DynamicApiController`1Proxy_5.ExecuteAsync_callback(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at Castle.Proxies.Invocations.ApiController_ExecuteAsync_5.InvokeMethodOnTarget()\r\n   at Castle.DynamicProxy.AbstractInvocation.Proceed()\r\n   at Abp.WebApi.Controllers.Dynamic.Interceptors.AbpDynamicApiControllerInterceptor`1.Intercept(IInvocation invocation)\r\n   at Castle.DynamicProxy.AbstractInvocation.Proceed()\r\n   at Castle.Proxies.DynamicApiController`1Proxy_5.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.d__1.MoveNext()"}*

The error only occurs after I added the first entry that has a `ParentId`

Model

```
     [Table("Categories")]
     public class Category : FullAuditedEntity
     {
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string SharepointMapping { get; set; }
        public int? ParentId { get; set; }
        public Category Parent { get; set; }
       public List<Category> Children { get; set; }
     }
```

CategoryAppService

```
  public ListResultDto<CategoryListDto> GetCategories(GetCategoriesInput input)
  {
    var categories = _categoryRepository
        .GetAll()
        .WhereIf(
            !input.Filter.IsNullOrEmpty(),
            p => p.Name.Contains(input.Filter) 
        )
        .OrderBy(p => p.Name)
        .ToList();

        return new ListResultDto<CategoryListDto>(categories.MapTo<List<CategoryListDto>>());
  }
```

CategoryListDto

```
[AutoMapFrom(typeof(Category))]
public class CategoryListDto : FullAuditedEntityDto
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string SharepointMapping { get; set; }
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Parent { get; set; }       
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default http-verb for all WebApi methods is **POST**.
Make your request with POST.

---

If you don't like this solution, you can use conventional verbs. With Conventional verbs, it looks the method name prefix and matches the related http-verb.

- GetCategories  -> HTTP-GET
- DeleteCategory -> HTTP-DELETE
- UpdateCategory -> HTTP-PUT
- CreateCategory -> HTTP-POST

you can use WithConventionalVerbs method as shown below:

```
Configuration.Modules.AbpWebApi().DynamicApiControllerBuilder
    .ForAll<IApplicationService>(Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(SimpleTaskSystemApplicationModule)), "tasksystem")
    .WithConventionalVerbs()
    .Build();
```

For further information:
https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Dynamic-Web-API

Comment: Your solution fixed half of the problem to help find the root cause which is the self referencing Json Error.